# Publish website with all .dll and .compiled file

Tags: dll, compilation, web, project, publish

I have a website project in VS2013.
Now How can I publish this website to file system, and publish all .dll and .compiled file (as photo : all page code publish to .compiled file)

[image: Website Project]

[image: All code file publish to .compiled file]

Thank for support.

Comment: When you right-click on the project name, is there not an option for "publish" or "deploy" or something of that nature?

Comment: It have "Publish website" but when I publish in "file system" method, it's not publish dll of reference and I don't know how to publish .compiled file.